# Oracle BPEL adds extra digits in decimal value

Tags: oracle, decimal, bpel

I have following expression in `Oracle bpel 11g`.

```
number(bpws:getVariableData('recommendedDeposit')) + number(bpws:getVariableData('delinquentTotalAmount')) + number(bpws:getVariableData('reconnectFee'))
```

Values of the 3 variables are

```
recommendedDeposit = 0
delinquentTotalAmount = 105.27
reconnectFee = 50
```

`Addition` of all 3 should be `155.27`.

I am assigning the result to a variable `var1`.

After the assign activity result shows as `155.26999999999998`.

What is problem here?

How can I get correct result of `155.27`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use format-number function within XSLT transformation.

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number($variable, precision)" />
```